# How to check using python's any() or next() functions the construct to see if element is present or not

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, list-comprehension, any

I have the following requirement where I want to check if a pattern is a substring of any of the list items. If not, then continue as follows:

```
for(feature in features):
    permissions = ['assets:analyticdn', 'assets.analyticun', 'assets1', 'assets2']
    present = False
    for(permission in permissions):
        if('assets:analytic' in permission):
           present = True
           break

    if present == False:
        continue # go to line ---> for(feature in features):

    # execute the rest of the code if present is True
```

Could this be shortened and written in a more pythonic way?

Comment: Again, what this code is **supposed** to do? As it is, you're checking if `'assets:analytic'` is a substring of any item in `permissions`, which is always true, because the first item in `permissions` is `'assets:analyticdn'`, which contains `'assets:analytic'`…

Comment: If you want to ask "is 'assets:analytic' a substring of any item in the permissions list?", you can use this: `if any('assets:analytic' in p for p in permissions):`

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need parentheses around `for` arguments or `if` conditions.

Second, you should swap your loops, because `permissions` do not depend on `feature`: you will make `len(features)` times the same test but you just need to make this test once.

Third, you have the "I want to continue the outer loop" problem. In some languages, you can put a label (`continue label`), but there is an obvious solution to this problem: create a function.

```
permissions = ['assets:analyticdn', 'assets.analyticun', 'assets1', 'assets2']
features = ["feature"]

def contains_analytic(permissions):
    for permission in permissions:
        if 'assets:analytic' in permission:
            return True

    return False

for feature in features:
    if not contains_analytic(permissions):
        continue

    # execute the rest of the code if present is True
```

Fourth, you may want to now which `permission` is found:

```
def find_analytic(permissions):
    for permission in permissions:
        if 'assets:analytic' in permission:
            return permission

    return None

for feature in features:
    permission = find_analytic(permissions)
    if permission is None:
        continue

    # execute the rest of the code if present is True
    print(feature, permission)
```

And now you can use a `next` and a generator:

```
def find_analytic(permissions):
    return next((p for p in permissions if 'assets:analytic' in p), None)

for feature in features:
    permission = find_analytic(permissions)
    if permission is None:
        continue

    # execute the rest of the code if present is True
    print(feature, permission)
```

I would keep the one line function because it explains *what* it does: you don't have to ask yourself what means this line or add a comment.

If you don't need the value of `permission`, then you can use `any('assets:analytic' in p for p in permissions)` as suggested by @John Gordon in a comment.